# How do I redirect any url/page in a sub folder to another URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a custom post type in Wordpress the following slug:

**domain.com/folder/page-1**

I want to redirect all /folder/ links/URLS to another URL.

For example:

1. **domain.com/folder/page-1**
2. **domain.com/folder/page-2**
3. **domain.com/folder/page-3**

All redirect to **domain.com/some-page**

Comment: If you are using WordPress you can change permanent URLs in your settings. Go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > Post name

Comment: I don't want to change the permalink structure for my whole site though.

Comment: You could use `RewriteCond` but I really don't recommend doing that, since .htaccess can be very tricky to debug. Can you not combine all of it in one file?

Comment: @Samuel Since I'm working with a custom post type in WordPress, it automatically adds "page-1,2,3..." in the "folder" sub folder. Here's how I'm using it. This is a fitness club's website. They have classes they add in a calendar. In order to add classes in the calendar, they have to create the class in a custom post type with just a title. Wordpress or the plugin is automatically giving each class their own page, which I just want it to show up on the calendar, not its own page. It's like this, .../classes/Zumba, classes/yoga/ and these are just blank pages. I'd rather forward them all.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^domain.com/folder/(.*)$ domain.com/some-page [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch directive for this :

```
RedirectMatch ^/folder/.+$ http://example.com/page
```

Comment: Wait, I thought you were spanish for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

If you have many URLs to redirects, its better to use plugins, suggest plugin [Simple 301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/)

Another methods is use wordpress function wp_redirect();

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_page_another_page');

if(!function_exists('redirect_page_another_page')){

   function redirect_page_another_page(){

   $queried_post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
   <!-- replace custom_post_type_name with you custom post type name -->
  if ( is_single() && 'custom_post_type_name' ==  $queried_post_type ) {
  $redirect_url = site_url().'/folder/some-page/';
  wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
  exit;
  }
 }
}
```